# DXA 2.1 with Tridion 9

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa-2.0, microservices

[image]

I am working on a Sites 9 + DXA 2.1 and trying to run the example site. When I run the site, it was throwing an exception for Context Service (Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: 'An error occurred while resolving evidence using the Context Service.'), so I commented that out in unity.config file, and after that I am able to run the site, but see below attached screenshot. It doesn't display any content of tridion though. Please suggest

Comment: Enable the log level to TRACE or DEBUG to see what it's going on both web app and as well as content and context services to trace the logs to understand what it's happening?

Comment: @Velmurugan Thanks, that helped. The context service was running on default port, 8087. But that port was  being already used, so I changed the port to 8089 and sample application started working. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the "SDL Web Context Service" and "SDL Web Content Service" is running properly and "ContextServiceCapability" and "ContentServiceCapability also properly registered in the discovery service.

```
<Role Name="ContextServiceCapability" Url="http://sdl.tridion.com:8081/context.svc"/>
<Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="http://sdl.tridion.com:8082/content.svc"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I did verify that both context and content service working fine.